# CSS - Is there a reason to have specific media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap uses the following media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Is there a reason why these queries have to be specific pixels?  I understand that 480px is the width of some specific devices, but since these are all based on ranges, would the following still work?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 999px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 799px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }
```

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: Yes, Of course it will still work.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.